# Import .csv file through SSIS Package without double Quotes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

SQL 2005

I am importing .csv file to SQL Table through SSIS Package !! On doing so, I am getting double quotes on every column header or field value !!

How to remove double quotes, while importing .csv file ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The csv file is using the `"` as a text qualifier.

When importing you must specify inform SSIS of this.

See [How to strip out double quotes from an import file in SQL Server Integration Services SSIS](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1316)

Answer (score 3):

Add " as the Text Qualifier when choosing the source (csv file)

http://twitpic.com/4k3ok8/full

Answer (score 1):

Enter " double quotes as the Text Qualifier.